# How to get the date in the form of month(string) day(int) year(int)?

Tags: python-3.x

I was wondering how to get the date in the form of month(string) day(int) year(int) using only python?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dparser` to get something similar:

```
import dateutil.parser as dparser
from datetime import datetime, date

today = date.today()
print(datetime.date(dparser.parse(str(today),fuzzy=True)).strftime("%B, %d, %Y"))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
April, 24, 2020
```

Comment: is it possible to take out the commas?